# Prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{|z|^n}{(2n)!}\leq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(|z|^\frac{1}{2})^n} {n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, inequality

I would like to ask how to prove the inequality: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{|z|^n}{(2n)!}\leq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(|z|^\frac{1}{2})^n}{n!}$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

I find this inequality in the steps of proving $\left|\cos\left(z^\frac{1}{2}\right)\right|\leq e^{|z|^\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: You are asked to prove $\cosh(\sqrt{|z|})\leq e^{\sqrt{|z|}}$, which is trivial, equivalent to $\sinh\sqrt{|z|}\geq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing the right-hand-side as the sum of the even part and the odd part:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(|z|^\frac{1}{2})^n}{n!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(|z|^\frac{1}{2})^{2k}}{(2k)!}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(|z|^\frac{1}{2})^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\geq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(|z|^\frac{1}{2})^{2k}}{(2k)!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{|z|^k}{(2k)!},$$
i.e.,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(|z|^\frac{1}{2})^n}{n!}\geq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{|z|^k}{(2k)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{|z|^n}{(2n)!}.$$

Comment: Thank you, I get it now.